# Slowest download speed with ethernet cable than usb wi-fi

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, download

I have an optic fiber connection on my home ( my vendor provides me with 250MB/s download speed and 250MB/s upload speed) with a Huawei EchoLife HG8546M router and I have a 15M long CAT6 ethernet cable and a TP-Link AC13000 USB WI-FI adapter.

On speedtest the results are 250MB/s download/upload with the ethernet cable and 68MB/s download/upload when I use the TP-Link.

But when I download a game from Steam or Battle.net using the ethernet cable the download speed starts from 28MB/s and then goes to some KB/s and back again (sometimes the download freeze too especially on Battle.net updates and I have to pause and unpause the update to start again) and when I use the WI-FI USB the download is stable at 5-7MB/s.

Does it have to do with long of the ethernet cable or a problem with my router?

Comment: More of the former than the latter, I'd say. Testing your connection speed is done with small size files, that usually take little to no time to cache and send. One big file takes a lot more time to download. You can try to set lower MTUs on your router and see if download speed is better, but a shorter Ethernet cable would be nice.

Comment: What many people do in a case like yours is to build a Steam cache server.  This allows for the cache server to keep the games downloaded, being updated in the background, allowing nearly instantaneous installs within your intranet on demand.  What I describe is well documented, and what you describe with regards to your download speeds, is a common problem with Steam hence the need for a cache server